# Where can I find how often my senator votes along party lines?

Tags: voting, legislative-process, legislation

I would like to know how partisan my Senators are. I have found various partisan rankings, but I am actually looking for a statistic of the % of time my Senators vote along party lines.

Comment: Which senators are you talking about?  Do you live in the US?  If so, which state to you live in?  Are you referring to State senators? or US senators?  Maybe you can give us the names of the senators who you're referring to.

Answer (score 4):

DW Nominate scores do [exactly that](http://voteview.com/dwnominate.asp). The closer to 1 the score is, the more your Senator votes with other conservatives. The closer to -1 the score is, the more your Senator votes with other liberals. 
Congress has been becoming more and more polarized since the 1980s, though Republicans at a rate several times faster than Democrats. If your Senator is a Republican and not John McCain, he probably votes consistently with other Republicans.

Comment: You have a reference for " though Republicans at a rate several times faster than Democrats"?

Comment: The link should give you historical DW Nominate scores, but a good illustration of this trend can be found at xkcd.com/1127, which graphs the scores rather well.

Comment: That data is not really human readable though...

Comment: It's not great, which is why I like the XKCD source as a visual representation.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [govtrack.us](https://www.govtrack.us), which computes *"Report Cards"* of how senators cluster along ideological lines.  [For 2017 **govtrack** reports](https://www.govtrack.us/congress/members/report-cards/2017/senate):

> Ideology Score
>   Our unique ideology analysis assigns a score to Members
>   of Congress according to their legislative behavior by how similar the
>   pattern of bills and resolutions they cosponsor are to other Members
>   of Congress. The score can be interpreted as a conservative—liberal
>   scale, although of course it only takes into account a small aspect of
>   reality.
>
> ALL SENATORS most conservative
>   1 1.00    Sen. James “Jim” Inhofe [R-OK]
>   2 0.99    Sen. Pat Roberts [R-KS]
>    ... EXPAND ...
>   99    0.06    Sen. Bernard “Bernie” Sanders [I-VT]
>   100   0.00    Sen. Alan “Al” Franken [D-MN, 2009-2017] most liberal

If we click [EXPAND](https://www.govtrack.us/congress/members/report-cards/2017/senate/ideology), the midlist Senators show a few Democrats rated more conservative than some Republicans:

> 44    0.74    Sen. Benjamin Sasse [R-NE]
>   45  0.74    Sen. John McCain
>   [R-AZ,1987-2018]
>   46  0.73    Sen. Richard Burr [R-NC]
>   47  0.72    Sen.
>   Joe Manchin [D-WV]
>   48  0.71    Sen. Joe Donnelly [D-IN]
>   49  0.69    Sen.
>   Richard Shelby [R-AL]
>   50  0.68    Sen. Bob Corker [R-TN]
>   51    0.67    Sen. Lamar Alexander [R-TN]
>   52  0.67    Sen. Lisa Murkowski
>   [R-AK]
>   53  0.61    Sen. Robert “Rob” Portman [R-OH]
>   54  0.59    Sen.
>   Bill Nelson [D-FL]
>   55  0.58    Sen. Heidi Heitkamp [D-ND]
>   56    0.57    Sen. Jon Tester [D-MT]
>   57  0.51    Sen. Angus King [I-ME]
>   58    0.51    Sen. Susan Collins [R-ME]
>   59  0.50    Sen. Claire McCaskill
>   [D-MO]